# Using exec.Command in golang, how do I open a new terminal and execute a command?

Tags: macos, go, terminal

I am able to get the following command to open a new terminal and execute the command when I directly input it inside a terminal, but I can not get it to work when I use the exec.Commmand function in go.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"'
```

I think the issue lies within the double and single quotes, but I am not exactly sure what is causing the error.

```
c := exec.Command("osascript", "-e", "'tell", "application", `"Terminal"`, "to", "do", "script", `"echo`, `hello"'`)
if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
     fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}
```

As of now the code is returning Error:  exit status 1, but I would like the code to open a terminal window and execute the command.

Comment: `tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"` is a single argument (the second) to osascript. https://play.golang.org/p/Rp_r8Jj7yve

Comment: I don't know about go but have you tried fixing the part of your code `\`"echo\`, \`hello"'\``

Comment: Thanks @Peter you are right it is one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing some time found this:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("osascript", "-s", "h", "-e",`tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo test"`)
```

Apparently you should give the automator script in 1 argument and also use ticks (`) as the string literals for go.

`"-s", "h"` is for automator program to tell you human readable errors.

My complete test code is as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
 )
// this is a comment

func main() {
    // osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"'
    cmd := exec.Command(`osascript`, "-s", "h", "-e",`tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo test"`)
    // cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "echo stdout; echo 1>&2 stderr")
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    slurp, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stderr)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", slurp)

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

PS: osascript is the command line interface for Automator app in macOS.

Comment: `\`osascript\` == "osascript"`, there is no difference at all in the actual string. You should normally only use backticks when necessary, and prefer double-quotes when possible.

Comment: difference is in the last part. It is tricky to give a script as an argument. So double quotes works in ticks.

Comment: yes, that's when you _would_ use `\`\`` to avoid escaping many quotes.